# Is there any way to pass a variable of class in other class?

Tags: c++

I want two classes. I have a static variable in class `Class1` and I want to pass the value that it got to class `Class2`.

For Example :

```
//Class1.h
{
    static int x;
    int Method1();
}

//Class1.cpp
{
    int Class1::x=0;
    int Class1::Method1(){
    x=2;
    }
}
```

Now Class2

```
//Class2.cpp
{
   Class1 cls;
   cout<<cls.x<<endl;//it shows 0 value
}
```

Comment: Do you know what is the use of static variables in C++?

Comment: please see my edited question in class2

Comment: This is not valid code. Please go pick up a book on C++ and come back to ask questions.

Comment: of course i know static variables and i used this way before,but this way does not answer to my question in my robotic soccer simulation field,because i wanted to use this to get information from on player to another player but now i understood we can not do this work,because the code runs for each player separately,anyway thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `x` is public:

```
#include "class1.h"

int xVal = Class1::x;
```

Comment: Otherwise add a simple static getter ;)

Comment: i didnt give -1,can you explain this like my code?thanks

Comment: @arash: It's better for you to pick a c++ book and start from there. You should at least understand the difference between class and object before moving forward

Comment: of course i know this way and i used this way before,but this way does not answer to my question in my robotic soccer simulation field,because i wanted to use this to get information from on player to another player but now i understood we can not do this work,because the code runs for each player separately,anyway thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the other class you want to access the variable from as "friend"

```
class Class1 {
    friend class Class2;
    // ...
}
```

Now you can access all variables from `Class1` in `Class2`.